# login failed with behat even the field names are correct

Tags: selenium, xpath, behat

I tried to login https://testinternal.com/login (internal website) with behat but I got the following error. I used Firefox developer to check the text field names, the field names are correct with username and password fields. Any ideas why it failed?

> 13:40:34.128 INFO - Executing: [get: https://testinternal.com])
>   13:40:34.249 INFO - Done: [get: https://testinternal.com/logon]
>   13:40:34.251 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.xpath:
>   //html/.//*[self::input | self::textarea | self::select][not(./@type =
>   'submit' or ./@type = 'image' or ./@type = 'hidden')][(((./@id =
>   'username' or ./@name = 'username') or ./@id =
>   //label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)), 'username')]/@for) or
>   ./@placeholder = 'username')] |
>   .//label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)),
>   'username')]//.//*[self::input | self::textarea |
>   self::select][not(./@type = 'submit' or ./@type = 'image' or ./@type =
>   'hidden')]]) 13:40:34.270 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.xpath:
>   //html/.//*[self::input | self::textarea | self::select][not(./@type =
>   'submit' or ./@type = 'image' or ./@type = 'hidden')][(((./@id =
>   'username' or ./@name = 'username') or ./@id =
>   //label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)), 'username')]/@for) or
>   ./@placeholder = 'username')] |
>   .//label[contains(normalize-space(string(.)),
>   'username')]//.//*[self::input | self::textarea |
>   self::select][not(./@type = 'submit' or ./@type = 'image' or ./@type =
>   'hidden')]]

```
    Feature: Sign in to the website
    In order to access the administrative interface
        As a visitor
        I need to be able to log in to the website

     @javascript
      Scenario: Log in with username and password                     # features/signin.feature:7
        Given I am on "/logon"                                        # Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext::visit()
        When I fill in the following:                                 # Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext::fillFields()
          | username | testuser |
          | password | testpwd  |
          Form field with id|name|label|value "username" not found.
        And I press "Sign in"                                         # Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext::pressButton()
        Then I should be on "http://testinternal.com"                 # Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext::assertPageAddress()
        And I should see "My Flows"                                   # Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext::assertPageContainsText()

    2 scenarios (2 failed)
    10 steps (2 passed, 6 skipped, 2 failed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the error that the element you are trying to locate is hidden. Selenium doesn't provide interaction with the hidden elements. There are two approach to solve this problem.

**Approach**:

1. Wait for element to be visible. You can check on what action your element is visible.
2. You can click using **JavaScript executor.**

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: Hi @Monika, yes the page is JavaScript based application. I'm able to control #1 approach. For #2 approach, where should I put this JavaScript executor? In behat features file?

Comment: Looks like for behat , you can just follow the first approach. Please go ahead and follow the first approach.I had given the solution by looking at the error.I am not sure how the second point is implemented in behat as I have never worked with behat. I can explore and let you know.

Comment: Sorry I had the typo, I am not able to control #1 because this application is done by dev team. My job is to automate the test cases

Comment: You mean to say you can do neither 1 nor 2?

Comment: how can you tell the elements are hidden? They are not saying in the error. When I view the source, I am unable to see the username and password fields. But when I run with Firefox developer I am able to see the field names

Answer (score 0):

In your context file, you can implement this method :

```
/**
 * @Then I press the button :label
 */
public function iPressTheButton($label)
{
    //#_submit is the selector "JS" of the button id of course !
    $submitTheLoginPage = 'document.querySelector("#_submit").click();';
    $this->getSession()->executeScript($submitTheLoginPage);

    //or

    $submitTheLoginPage = 'document.querySelector("#_submit").click();';
    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript($submitTheLoginPage);
}
```

Hope it works !.

Khalid